# How may I completely bypass standard DNS on Android 12?

Tags: android-12, dns, private-dns

The Android 12 private DNS setting is unfortunately not set up to accept an IP address, only a hostname. Thus, it clearly must resolve a standard DNS query before doing the TLS or HTTPS query.

I frequently find my connection working but with no standard DNS response.

Is there any way on Android 12 to completely bypass standard DNS?

Comment: The purpose of "private DNS" is to keep the host names private you use when using Android. With private DNS only the DNS server name is queried so unless you use a custom DNS server that is only used by you there is no privacy issue.

Comment: if the standard dns query is man-in-the-middle hijacked, the entire ensuing private dns connection can also be hijacked, thus i claim it defeats the purpose!  But i've edited that out now because it's aside from the point of my question.